# I am a Sixth Form student who needs to use 3D CAD software for my project. Any clue on how to do this?

Tags: software-installation, 3d

I have been given Windows running copies of the software, but am unsure as to whether there is a reliable, safe way to run the software without ruining the security and reliability of my distro. I no longer have Windows as it was wiped from my system.

Anything to help?

Comment: Do you need to use specific 3D CAD software - if so what software is it? Some may work with wine. Or, if anybody knows of anything suitable could you use different 3D CAD software?

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenSCAD

> OpenSCAD is a software for creating solid 3D CAD models. It is free
>   software and available for Linux/UNIX, Windows and Mac OS
>   X.<sup>[OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/index.html)</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install openscad
```